# Integral of a product divded by a sum of Gaussian PDFs

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be the PDFs of two Gaussian distributions both with zero mean, and variances $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ respectively.

I'm trying to compute
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(x) g(x)}{f(x)+g(x)}dx
$$
but I am unable to make any progress.

I can also use the fact that the product of two Gaussian densities is an (unnormalized) Gaussian in the same variable to simplify the numerator but this doesn't seem to help.

I would also settle for upper/lower bounds. For example you can bound point-wise $f(x)+g(x)$ with another scaled Gaussian.

We can also assume $\sigma_2 = c \sigma_1$ for some constant $c$ if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\sigma_1<\sigma_2.$ Writing $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{1+\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f^{n+1}(x)}{g^n(x)}dx$$ you land on the series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{a^nb}{\sqrt{n+c}}$$ where $a,b,c$ are easyly computable, but not the sum of the series.

Comment: The ratio of Gaussian densities is again another unnormalized Gaussian (http://davmre.github.io/blog/statistics/2015/03/27/gaussian_quotient). So we can write $\frac{f(x)}{1+c \cdot h(x)}$.